# 8086 - assembly, mov operation after array declaration in 8086 microprocessor

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

```
array db 4, 2, 3   ; declaring an array

mov al, array[0]   ; moving the first element of the array to the ax register
```

after the execution of this code in **emu8086** the final value of al was 2

Comment: usr2564301 i edited my code check it out

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to put the space for the array in this data section.  As is, the CPU tries to execute the contents of `array` as code, leading to meaningless results.